# Is there a shorter or L-shaped version of PowerPole connector? if not, is there an engineering reason why not?

Tags: connector

I've not worked with [this connector](http://modernroboticsinc.com/powerpole-extension-cable-kit) in many years.  I'm working with a robotics team and these connectors are very long and bulky and take up [more, think] space [than they need to ].  I'm trying to find a shorter or L-shaped version. Have found none, wondering if I missed it or if there is an *engineering reason* why they can't be made that way.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're built that way because they are optimized for 1. Power handling and 2. Cost.

The pins are sheet metal construction (folded from a flat sheet) and typically tin-plated copper. As such cannot rely on a solid core to improve conduction and better materials (e.g. gold) to reduce resistance.

All they have to work with is surface area and since the diameter of the pin must remain small enough to retain strength (it's a rolled up sheet) yet large enough to be manipulated by conventional forming equipment, the only degree of freedom left is the length... ergo the longer pins.

[image]

Comment: If the connector was L shaped it would be impossible to push the spring contact assembly into the plastic housing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the text you linked to, the connector is rated for 45 A. This requires a fairly large contact surface area between the two parts of the connector. Apparently the designers of this connector chose to make it long and narrow rather than short and wide.

However, it also says the wire is "14 or 16 gauge". According to the first ampacity table I found online, 16 gauge is limited to about 22 A for "chassis wiring" (Different standards might give slightly different ampacities, based on different assumptions about airflow conditions and allowed temperature rise of the wire).

So either the wire is undersized for the connector, or the connector is over-specified for the wire. If your current requirement is less than 25 A, you can almost certainly find a more compact connector able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the specific connectors you have linked to, but here is a general idea. Connector design depends on largely three things:

1. How much current do the contacts carry. This determines the conductor and contact area. Higher the current, larger the conductor contact area you need. If the area is too small, the contact will have high resistance and start heating up.
2. Voltage and insulation. The voltage between adjacent pins determines the distance and and the insulation between between adjacent connectors: for instance a 5V connector can have pins a few mm apart, not so for a 400V rated connector.
3. Reliability and mating cycles:
   Some connectors are designed for repeated plug-and unplug, some are intended to be connected/disconnected infrequently only during install or service, which also determines the size and strength of the connector as a whole.

Based on the criteria you can surely find other connectors, selecting one based on your tradeoffs.